# Swift - Forming an array from a JSON Response

Tags: ios, json, swift, get

I am new to the world of JSON. I just got started with JSON in Swift.

Right now, I have the following function:

```
func forShow() {
    // Using ACORN API to fetch the course codes

    guard let url[enter image description here][1]Online = URL(string: "https://timetable.iit.artsci.utoronto.ca/api/20179/courses?code=CSC") else { return }
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: urlOnline) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {
            print(data)
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

I get a response with all courses having 'CSC' in their code String. I want to form an array with all complete course codes based on the response. I will paste response for one course here:

[image]

So, I want to access all the course codes seen in the image. It's "CSC104H1-F-20179" I want to to be able to access.

Comment: The response can be accessed at:  https://timetable.iit.artsci.utoronto.ca/api/20179/courses?code=CSC

Answer (score 0):

Treat your JSON like a dictionary. You have all the course names at the top level, so fortunately you don't have to dig deep in the hierarchy.

So, where you have:
`let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
print(json)`

Change to:
`if let arrayOfCourses = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [[String: Any]] {
    for (course, _) in arrayOfCourses {
        print(course)
    }
}`